# Observe org.eclipse.jface.text.IDocument content

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-databinding

There is a [Text](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/widgets/Text.html) control bound to a model with [WidgetProperties.text()](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jface/databinding/swt/WidgetProperties.html#text%28int%29). I'm going to promote it to [TextViewer](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jface/text/TextViewer.html). TextViewer uses [IDocument](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jface/text/IDocument.html) as its input, so WidgetProperties.text() seems to be inapplicable now. How do I keep the text in the control bound to my model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is anything for observing `IDocument`.

`TextViewer` uses the `StyledText` control to present the text, use `TextViewer.getTextWidget()` to access. `WidgetProperties.text()` supports observing `StyledText`.